# Difference between TRY and try

Tags: c++

Going over some legacy code I noticed that in some cases the `TRY`.. `CATCH` macros are used and in other cases the keywords `try`.. `catch`.

Is there a functional difference between the two options?

Comment: Depends on how the macros are defined, since this is non-standard to my knowledge.

Comment: @StoryTeller they are not standard

Comment: That will depend on the definition of the `TRY`/`CATCH` macros. There's too little contect to asnwer from what you have given.